# Sort data according to code in column in R

Tags: r, sorting, transpose

I have a file with two columns. One with a 5 digit code and one with counts.
Here is an example with 3 digits:

```
Code    Count
101   1254
103   1566
221   459
213   698
```

Now I would like to transpose the data so that it is sorted after that code starting with the last digit:

```
        10x   11x 12x 13x 14x .... 19x  20x 21x 22x 23x 
xx1   1254                                      459
xx2             
xx3   1566                                  698
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example you could do something like this:

```
df$code_2 <- substr(df$Code, 1, 2)
df$code_1 <- substring(df$Code, 3)
```

Which looks like:

```
> df
  Code Count code_2 code_1
1  101  1254     10      1
2  103  1566     10      3
3  221   459     22      1
4  213   698     21      3
```

And then `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, code_1 ~ code2, value.var = 'Count')

  code_1   10  21  22
1      1 1254  NA 459
2      3 1566 698  NA
```

And to format it properly:

```
rownames(df2) <- paste0('xx', df2$code_1)
df2$code_1 <- NULL
names(df2) <- paste0(names(df2), 'x')
```

OUtput:

```
df2
     10x 21x 22x
xx1 1254  NA 459
xx3 1566 698  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do:

```
# create a sample dataset
data <- data.frame(Code = c(101,103,221,213), Count = c(1254,1566,459,698))

# extract code start and end
start <- sort(unique(substr(data$Code, 1,2)))
end <- sort(unique(substr(data$Code, 3,3)))

# create placeholder dataframe
data2 <- sapply(start, paste0, end)
# where code not in original dataset, write NA
data2[!sapply(c(data2), '%in%', data$Code)] <- NA
# else write the appropriate count
data2[sapply(c(data2), '%in%', data$Code)] <- data$Count[order(data$Code)]
# change column and row names
colnames(data2) <- paste0(start, "x")
rownames(data2) <- paste0("xx", end)
```

But I would guess `dcast` as in LyzandeR's answer is more elegant.